# Can I use hasOneThrough two relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have four tables with **one¹-to-many*** relationships like below:

**A** ¹ ⎯ * **B** ¹ ⎯ * **C** ¹ ⎯ * **D**

- **D** has one **C**,
- **C** has one **B**,
- **B** has one **A**.

In **D** model, I have:

```
**
 * Get B.
 */
public function b()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(B::class, C::class);
}
```

Can I have another function to get **A** from **D** through **C** and **B** ?